# Get first letter of word in statement

Tags: laravel

I have a statement like "Animal Association" from the database. I want to get its short form. It means, only the first letter of each word like this "AA". In the blade file, I got the whole statement as follows,

```
<p>{{ $animal->user->club->name}}</p>
```

So, how can I get a short form of this name?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MySQL 8+, then a raw select with `REGEXP_REPLACE` should work here:

```php
$users = DB::table('animals')
    ->select(DB::raw("SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(name, '(\\w)\\w+\\s*', '$1')"))
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

This very common problem where we ran into, I can provide you a function that will solve your problem.  I am sharing two solutions and you can use any of these solutions.

### using function

You can use this function in your model and solve your problem.

```
public function getNameAbbreviate($string){
    $abbreviation = "";
    $string = ucwords($string);
    $words = explode(" ", "$string");
      foreach($words as $word){
          $abbreviation .= $word[0];
      }
   return $abbreviation; 
}
```

There is probably no one-line solution, the solution which I provided is readable and understandable.

### using regex

This solution is easy to apply and in case you can't make the first method work then go with this.

```
<p>{{ preg_split("/\s+/", $animal->user->club->name) }}</p>
```

> using regex we can get a direct solution but I personally don't like it or recommend it.